# Android pass a 2d int array from one activity to another ERROR

Tags: java, android, arrays, 2d

ACTIVITY 1:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("CustomLevelData",  LevelCreator.LCLevelData);
Intent i = new Intent(LevelCreatorPopout.this, GameView.class);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

ACTIVITY 2:

```
LevelData=(int[][]) extras.getSerializable("CustomLevelData");
```

ERROR:
`E/AndroidRuntime(16220): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(16220): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.powerpoint45.maze/com.powerpoint45.maze.GameView}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to int[][]`

I have searched but found nothing on 2d INT array passing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Serializable, it's better to use [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) from a performance point of view to pass non- primitive data.

Not sure if this is the best idea, but you can define a class which contains the 2d-array and which implements Parcelable. You can then pass an instance of that class from an activity using:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
// Assume MyClass is the class which contains the 2d-array
intent.putExtra("key", myclassObj); //value being the instance/object of MyClass that you want to pass
```

You can retrieve it in another activity using:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
MyClass mc = (MyClass)bundle.getParcelable("key");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you still want to stick with Serializable, you have to break it in the second activity and do a loop.

```
Bundle dataBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
int[][] levelData = new int[3][3];

Object[] temp = (Object[])dataBundle.getSerializable("CustomLevelData");
if(temp != null){
    levelData = new int[temp.length][];
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
        levelData[i] = (int[])temp[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

WHAT I DID:

make class

```
package com.powerpoint45.maze;
```

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class SerializableCustomData implements Parcelable{

```
public int[][] ints;

public int[][] getints() {
    return ints;
}

public void setints(int[][] ints) {
    this.ints = ints;
}

public SerializableCustomData() {
    ints = new int[1][1];
}

public SerializableCustomData(Parcel in) {
    ints = (int[][]) in.readSerializable();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeSerializable(ints);

}
public static final Parcelable.Creator<SerializableCustomData> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<SerializableCustomData>() {

    @Override
    public SerializableCustomData createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new SerializableCustomData(in);
    }

    @Override
    public SerializableCustomData[] newArray(int size) {
        return new SerializableCustomData[size];
    }
};
```

}

SET IT N PASS IT

```
SerializableCustomData myParcelable = new SerializableCustomData();
            myParcelable.setints(LevelCreator.LCLevelData);

            Intent i = new Intent(LevelCreatorPopout.this, GameView.class);
            i.putExtra("parcel",myParcelable);
            startActivity(i);
```

GRAB IT

```
SerializableCustomData myParcelable = extras.getParcelable("parcel");
            LevelData = myParcelable.getints();
```